# Anti-collision Capabilities of MFRC522

Tags: rfid, mfrc522

I'm a Computer Engineering student, and my full knowledge of RFIDs is limited to the research I have conducted thus far (mainly using this site).  As such, there are still some general concerns I have that I could not find direct answers to.

My current intent is to use an RFID reader module (possibly the MFRC522) connected to a microcontroller (I currently use a TM4C123GH6PM, but would switch to Arduino if it would be easier) to read in ~60 RFID tags stacked directly on top of each other.

As I have understood thus far, to do so would require the use of a reader which supports anti-collision.  After discovering the MFRC522 supports this, my new question has become - is there a limit to the number of tags the reader can handle?  I understand that the reader's range could be problematic, but this aside, would it be able to handle that many tags?  I suspect that this will not be the case, and if not, what kind of things should I be looking for in a reader in order to handle such a scenario?

I'll reiterate - I only have a very basic understanding of RFIDs.  I am much more educated in handling the microcontroller, and for my current project I would like to utilize a reader module to handle a scenario of ~60 stacked tags.  Thanks in advance for any feedback on this situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anticollision for Mifare Type technology is capable of selecting as much transponders as the UID length is. For a 7 Byte Type UID (E.g. Desfire) there could be 256^7 tags selected. Here You find the reference for this: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10833.pdf
Because of power Limitation, practically you can not read out more than 5-10 transponders.